# Hashing Salting

Tags: php, security, encryption, hash, sha

Hello sorry if this may be a stupid question, I am gonna try a sha+salt for my site. wondering how to randomize my salt. Upon registering so both of them will be hashed into the database. Also is there a need for me to decrpyt both sha and salt for user validation. Would be nice if someone pointed me in the right detection or a good article. Thanks Also I'm new to security stuff on websites I'm still researching what security implementations i would use for my site currently these are what i will be doing.

1. password hashing
2. Anti-SQL injections
3. Hiding Values in URL

Would like to know more what should i add to my security. I am making a school management system as a Project.

So far i am looking Into. Anti-bruteforce and my professor gave me a hint about HTTPS.

Also how would i validate a log in if the password is sha+salt encrypted.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php http://phpsec.org/projects/guide/ http://php.robm.me.uk/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is quite a large question its probably easier for me to direct you to some useful resources rather than try to explain it all myself.

For an introduction to web cryptography A List Apart [wrote a nice article](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/web-cryptography-salted-hash-and-other-tasty-dishes/). It doesn't discuss implementation very much, but provides a nice overview.

For a list of security flaws and how to combat them see the [OWASP Top Ten Project](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project).

Here's a guide to [PHP Security](http://phpsec.org/projects/guide/) that is pretty comprehensive.

Finally, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords) for more on creating a login system.

I'd recommend searching around Stack Overflow as there're probably some good answers to questions you may have.

Comment: Thank you this is what i would like. I know this is a huge problem appreciate that you direct me.

Answer (score 1):

Being the salt just a random string added to the hash of the string you want to encode, there are enough ways to generate it [e.g. [this on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235434/how-to-generate-a-random-long-salt-for-use-in-hashing)].

You don't need and you can't decrypt any sha result because sha [like md5] is an **hashing** algorithm, not a **crypt** function, i.e. it's not meant to hide anything for later retrieval: this is important because I don't want the admin of a site I am registered to to read my password from database.

To hash is to map elements from a data set to shorter elements from another one, in an [almost total] [injective way](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function) - you map arbitrary long strings to fixed-length keys: this lets you make comparison in the hashed domain without actually knowing the original value.

```
hash( value1 ) = hash ( value2 ) => value1 = value2
```

I said *almost* because hashing algorithms have some collisions [e.g. exceptions to previous statement such as `hash(value1) = hash(value2)` does not imply the 2 values being the same] - salts help in this regard too.

This said, this is how you save the password to db:

- generate the salt;
- **prepend** the salt to the actual password: it's important to put it *before* the pwd to prevent [dictionary attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionary_attack);
- [hash](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php) the concatenated string with a proper algorithm [I chose `sha1` just for example's sake];
- save both the string and the salt to db.

In code:

```
$user -> salt = your_salt_generator();
$user -> hashedPwd = hash('sha1', $salt . $userChosenPwd);
```

Pwd checking against `$username` / `$password` is just:

- get user with given `$username` from db;
- if it exists, use process above with saved salt and given password and check if it equals stored hash.

In code:

```
hash('sha1', $user -> salt . $sentPassword) == $user -> hashedPwd;
```

---

About hiding values in URLs, it's more a SEO / readability topic than a security one: URLs should be made upon routing [e.g. `http://somesite.com/products/:id` to access the id-th product], and your server logic should not be vulnerable to stuff put into requests that are made to your site [regardless to totally crap cases I can't come with right now].

---

Regarding MySQL injections, we got rid of them since [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) from [PDO extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

There are millions of answers about this around SO, just have a look around.

Keep it up with your work!

Comment: Thank you! gonna present this in 4 days. The only remaining this i gotta do is Design, Security and Print Algorithm(Simple counting values in database). =D

Comment: -1 for using a single iteration hash function for password hashing.

Answer (score 1):

Not really a direct answer to your question, but look into phpass
http://www.openwall.com/phpass/

It will handle the salting for you, and has been reviewed by many security experts and been deemed and extremely good password hashing tool