# Unique generated SALT for each user?

Tags: php, hash, sha1, salt

I'd like to ask if it's possible to generate a unique salt for each user and then hash it like
`sha1(sha1($password . $salt))`
so the $salt is a randomly generated string?.

If yes, how would I encrypt the password on login?

Xenforo uses this, and I am wondering how are they encrypting the passwords if they are using unique salt for each user?.

Many thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2235548/251311

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Don't make your own password hashing algorithm](http://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm). It's going to be easily crackable and your users won't appreciate their passwords being stolen when your database is compromised.

Bcrypt and other well-tested hashes do this already:

```
>>> bcrypt.generate_password_hash('password', 15)
    '$2a$15$bzaLXuer1C8dtSckDp3AI.eOoL/nOTsSdpjEMyDMcJ3ZQELdRcLzq'
>>> bcrypt.generate_password_hash('password', 15)
    '$2a$15$Ye.cFInKhzo1KvAJGSi6yORV5uEqeW.Z1oAhdfi.163Psz4YPA3CO'
```

The random salt and the number of rounds are stored within the hash itself, separated by a delimiter, which lets the constant-time password checking function pick the salt out of the resulting hash string.

If for some *other* reason you need to create secure random strings, use [`openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php):

```
$bytes = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(64, true);
$hex = bin2hex($bytes);
```